# SWIG, OpenCOBOL and mixing targets

Tags: c, swig, gnucobol

OpenCOBOL uses intermediate C source on the way to compiled binary, giving it access to the entire libc universe.  With a goal of centralized embedding of more than one SWIG wrapper:

```
cobc -C nextbig.cob
swig -java nextbig.i
gcc nextbig.c nextbig_wrapper.c
gcc -shared ...
```

and gcc builds a very nice binary, Java and the C output of the COBOL compiler mixed nicely.

Only tested `swig -tcl`, `-perl`, `-python` and `-java` so far (all different `nextbig_wrapper.c` of course).

How much grief would be involved in blending (for instance) `swig -java` and `swig -python` across the same `nextbig.c` and `nextbig.i`?  Is there a known idiom for manual intervention at managing two or more target `_wrapper.c` files?  Or is it a known thing not to do?